# How to remove duplicate results based on an aggregate field?

Tags: sql

I have created an aggregate of `fieldA` and `fieldB` (fieldA_field_B) as `new_field`. How to remove duplicate rows from the results based on that field alone? Using `min()` it still comes up with he same results.

```
select concat(fieldA,'_',fieldB) as new_field,
field c,
field d
from tableA
where field ='false' and fieldy='true'
group by 2,3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the combination of CTE and Row_number(), we can remove the duplicate records from the table.
This will find the duplicate records based on "fieldA" and "fieldB" (fieldA_field_B) and delete it from the table:

```
With CTE As
    (
        select *, row_number() over(partition by concat(fieldA,'_',fieldB) order by fieldA, fieldB) as RN
        from tableA
        where field ='false' and fieldy='true'
    )
delete from CTE where RN>1;
```

Please let me know if any information is needed on this. Thanks!